# Cythony c-library 2D array

Tags: arrays, numpy, cython

so I'am trying to interface a c-library to control a mcc data acquisition device using cython however I've come across the following problem how to interface a C-library function taking a 2D array as an argument:

```
void usbBuildCalTable_USB1608FS(libusb_device_handle *udev, 
       Calibration_AIN table[NGAINS_USB1608FS][NCHAN_USB1608FS]);
```

the function is defined as above. I tried to interface the function in the pxd-file via:

```
void usbBuildCalTable_USB1608FS(libusb_device_handle *udev, 
       Calibration_AIN *table)
```

and as expected I go an error saying:

```
expected ‘struct Calibration_AIN (*)[8]’ but argument is of type ‘struct Calibration_AIN *’
```

now if I declare the function in the pxd as follows:

```
void usbBuildCalTable_USB1608FS(libusb_device_handle *udev, 
       Calibration_AIN *table[NCHAN_USB1608FS])
```

the compilation complains that NCHAN_USB1608FS is not static even though it is a define value in the c-functions header file and was declared in the pxd as

```
int  NCHAN_USB1608FS
```

any ideas how I can declare the function correctly?

Comment: Your definition should probably be `const int NCHAN_USB1608FS = 8;` adding the `const` to turn it to a compile-time initialization.

Comment: the declaration in the pxd-file has to be `enum: NCHAN_USB1608FS` that way the compiler will treat the value as constant. Thx to 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/-fLG08E5lYM